# Matlab z buffer for simulating kinect

Tags: matlab, kinect, depth-buffer

We are trying to simulate simple kinect output.

I have rendered a triangle mesh in Matlab and now I want to get at the depth buffer of the figure/axis where the shape has been rendered.
How do I do that in matlab? i.e. how do I access the depth buffer of a figure?

Comment: I have done something similar where I wrote a raycasting algorithm to simulate such output. It never really worked too well (very slow on large meshes). I'd be interested to know if you can get it directly from a figure, as this would be much easier...

Comment: I guess your real question is how to get access to the JOGL objects used by MatLab's own figures?

Comment: That sounds like a good way to phrase it. I didnt realize Matlab figures were JOGL objects.

Comment: Could any one find the solution of this problem ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt, are you sure that they are JOGL objects and not JFrame objects? Does Matlab necessarily use OpenGL? Is there a chance it uses direct canvas drawing instead? In either case the question is still open and I have left a 300 bounty on it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-jogl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer

Comment: @twerdster: I know MatLab uses OpenGL for rendering.  I don't know which wrapper it uses, could be JOGL, could be something else.

Comment: The question has been answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-opengl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer/8919803#8919803

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31229-zorder-getset/content/ZOrderSet.m).

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what we are looking for at all. We need a per pixel depth value for the current figure output.