# Matlab: fast image capture by copying the backing store / back buffer?

Tags: matlab, graphics, real-time, screen-capture, double-buffering

I am using version R2007a.

First for a little background: I am creating a tool that accumulates a scatter plot from data acquired in real time.  When the number of points gets large enough, the graphics refresh can't keep up with the incoming data, so I am using `'painters'` with `'EraseMode'` set to `'none'` and simply doing a `set(obj,'xdata',...,'ydata',...)` to update the plot point position. This works very nicely.

Incidentally, I discovered a nice trick: by turning on double buffering, MATLAB always has a copy of the image in memory, so points accumulate in the image even when the window is hidden or minimized!

Now I would like to capture each image to create a movie.  I have seen a variety of solutions using `getframe()`, `addframe()`, and the undocumented `hardcopy()`.  These all redraw the figure and the old points are lost, but this is actually something I can work around in post-processing.  My issue is that these functions are too slow for the data acquisition rate.  With tic/toc, I find

```
tic, getframe(h); toc - 0.13 sec
tic, addframe(h); toc - 0.15 sec
tic, hardcopy(h,'-Dpainters','r0'); toc - 0.07 sec
```

I see that `hardcopy()` does something different with `'renderer'` set to `'painters'`, but even if I could find out how to make of use of its output, it's still too slow.

But with double buffering on, the image is already sitting in the backing store / back buffer.  Making a copy of that would be quite fast.  Can any hackers out there figure out how to get a pointer to the backing store and make a copy of it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just store the incoming real-time data in a file, play it back later (plot each frame) and make a video out of that, rather than trying to create the video in real-time as well?

Comment: Also, you may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-opengl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer) interesting, as it has a method of accessing the figure's pixels directly when the OpenGL renderer is used.

Comment: I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071607/matlab-using-the-gpu-for-saving-an-image-off-a-figure 
What do you mean by " turning on double buffering"?

Comment: It seems that hardcopy (and all other methods) re-render the figure.