# matlab: using the GPU for saving an image off a figure

Tags: matlab, opengl, rendering, gpu, matlab-figure

I use matlab to render a complex mesh (using trimesh, material, camlight, view...) and need not display it to the user, just to get the rendered image. [This is discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137628/render-matlab-figure-in-memory).

Using any of the suggested solutions (save-as image, saving into a video object, and using undocumented `hardcopy`) is very slow (~1sec), especially compared to rendering the plot itself, including painting on the screen takes less than 0.5sec.

I believe it is caused by `hardcopy` method not to utilize the GPU, while rendering the original plot for display do use the GPU; using GPU-Z monitor software I see the GPU working during ploting but not during `hardcopy`.

The figure use 'opengl' as renderer, but `hardcopy`, which is the underlying implementation of all the suggested methods, don't seem to respect this...

Any suggestion on how to configure it to use the GPU?

EDITED: following [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56433-is-there-a-computationally-fast-way-to-save-figures-as-pictures) I've moved to use the following, but GPU usage is still a flatliner.

```
  cdata=hardcopy(f, '-Dopengl', '-r0')
```