# Rendering a 3D model in matlab

Tags: graphics, matlab, matlab-figure, 3d-model

I am trying to render these models in Matlab so that I can sample them and then use their shape for my research work.

My question is that: Is there a way to render 3D models, used in different 3D graphics engines, in Matlab?

I have found something [similar](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=917) but it only loads an obj mesh.

Update:
I have also found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-opengl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer) which uses OpenGL function in a mex file to access the graphics of a figure and get the depth buffer. However what I am trying to do is to render a model within a matlab figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/projects/poses/

I understand that it's still not completely stable, but they're working on it.

Anyway, this lets you render to a matrix and then do whatever you like with it (imshow it, imwrite it, etc.)