# MATLAB: Can I Save the Z-Buffer Array Values?

Tags: matlab, zbuffer

I am new to MATLAB and am wondering if anybody could help me with this (probably basic) question:

I would like to view/save the depth value for each screen pixel (the z-buffer) of a 3D surf(), ideally in a file.
I have read [Using OpenGL in Matlab to get depth buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-opengl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer/8919803#8919803) which was helpful but I can't seem to figure out how to save the buffer values instead of just outputting them as an image.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! If you read the accepted answer to that question carefully, you will notice the line `imshow(depthMap, []);` in the function `trytodisplaydepthmap`. This displays the depth data captured in the matrix `depthMap` as an image. Just change this function to do with the data what ever else you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenGL in Matlab to get depth buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862467/using-opengl-in-matlab-to-get-depth-buffer)