# get simulated depth image from matlab figure

Tags: matlab, opengl, simulation, depth, zbuffer

I'm simulating a depth camera in matlab (and I don't have the automated driving toolbox) and was trying to access the depth buffer (z-buffer) from the figure that matlab plots.

I've implemented twerdster's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919803/2985406), but the depthData returns an empty 0x1084895568 size array.

I compiled the mex function with debug on and checked it out in visual studio (following [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html) guide) and I saw that `glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);` is setting `viewport` to `[0, 0, 1084895568, 0]`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you even have a valid GL context bound to your thread when you are calling that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how matlab uses openGL, but I did confirm openGL was being used by running `fig.Renderer` which returned `'opengl'`